# mosfet p-channel doesn't work?

Tags: mosfet

I have this circuit that has a p-channel MOSFET driving a motor. The motor is supposed to go when I press the button. However when I apply power to my circuit the motor runs without pressing the button.

[image: This is my circuit]

Comment: Looks like you have drain and source reversed

Comment: The way you have connected your p chan fet its actually a foward biased diode ,so no wonder the motor wont stop.Reverse DS like Icy stated.

Comment: Also your Voltmeter is rather pointless since it will always read 12V (on a simulated circuit like that, where there's no rail drop or ground bounce). I suspect you wanted to connect it across the load or across the MOSFET.

Comment: After edit your MOSFET is still wrong and your meter is still just reading the power supply. And, while you're at it, R8 is unnecessarily low - a 1k will do fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your base is floating and hence-forth susceptible to noise. This is true for both the transistor and the PMosfet you are using. Floating gate and bases are quite susceptible to spurious noises and can behave wierd.

Give a pull down from the base to the ground. Also the PMOSFET you are using is in the wrong way. For a P channel MOSFET to work, or for that matter any MOSFET , make sure you have a min Vgs > Vth(threshold voltage). Now, for the P Mosfet the gate voltage should be < than Voltage of Source and for the NMOsfet Vg(gate voltage)> Vs(source voltage).

Here when the transistor is on the gate is pulled down to GND and thats good. But the source is not properly connected to the supply.

Comment: A MOSFET wired the wrong way (S and D swapped) will always conduct through its body diode, so will always be on. Since he seems to be asking about the simulated circuit rather than a real one, I suspect that is actually the main/only error. The other things you've said are important though in a physically realized circuit.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff. I doubt if he wants it that way. And ofcourse  there are many MOSFETs without body diode. I think he flipped it by mistake.

Comment: Notes only: Gate is NOT floating as shown - it's pulled high. | AQ very small %age of MOSFETS have no body diode. For practical purposes almost all encountered in everyday use have them.

Comment: Yes my bad. Gate is not floating. But, still feel the MOSFET is flipped for the system.